# DELPHI/INDY/IdHTTP Log into invision power board forum?

Tags: delphi, authentication, indy, idhttp

Need help keeping a session after logging into forum. 
I'm using TIdHttp and have a cookie manager assigned already

```
  Http.Get(Url); //..Used to get session Id that is then stored in FSessionID

  Param := TStringList.Create;
  Param.Add('act=Login');
  Param.Add('CODE=01');
  Param.Add('s='+FSessionID);
  Param.Add('referer=''''');
  Param.Add('CookieDate=1');
  Param.Add('UserName=MYUsername');
  Param.Add('PassWord=MyPassword');
  Http.Post(Url,Param); //..The was Login succesfull. Made sure by checking responce
  Http.Get(Url); //..Now its not logged in. Why????
```

Comment: Which version of indy are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the SessionID cookie is not being rejected by TIdCookieManager when it arrives.  Indy's cookie support is currently broken, causing valid cookies to sometimes be ignored instead of stored.

Answer (score 0):

It appears in your Post that you are providing the session as a parameter...which would make me assume that you would need to provide the session as a parameter in your Get as well. (The cookie doesn't appear to be used.)

Perhaps you include the session as part of the URL, as in:

```
Http.Get(URL + '?s=' + fSessionID)
```